# How can i generate dynamic tree view in jsp using struts 1.3.10?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, struts-1

Please help me, how can i display dynamic tree view in JSP?

This is my STATIC tree view:

[image: Static Tree View]

Here is coding for above output:

```
<li> <a href=#><span class=icon-cogs></span> Expired</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=component_blocks.html>Blocks and panels</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_buttons.html>Buttons</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_modals.html>Modals and popups</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_tabs.html>Tabs, accordion</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_progress.html>Progressbars</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_lists.html>List groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_messages.html>Messages</a></li>
                        <li> <a href=#>Tables<i class="icon-angle-down pull-right"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=component_table_default.html>Default tables</a></li>
                                <li><a href=component_table_sortable.html>Sortable tables<i class="icon-angle-down pull-right"></i></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href=component_layout_blank.html>Default layout(blank)</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=component_layout_custom.html>Custom navigation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=component_layout_scroll.html>Content scroll</a></li>
                                        <li><a href=component_layout_fixed.html>Fixed content</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href=#>Layouts<i class="icon-angle-down pull-right"></i></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=component_layout_blank.html>Default layout(blank)</a></li>
                                <li><a href=component_layout_custom.html>Custom navigation</a></li>
                                <li><a href=component_layout_scroll.html>Content scroll</a></li>
                                <li><a href=component_layout_fixed.html>Fixed content</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href=component_charts.html>Charts</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_maps.html>Maps</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_typography.html>Typography</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_gallery.html>Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_calendar.html>Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href=component_icons.html>Icons</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

But i want this output for dynamic tree view from DataBase using(**ArrayList**) in Struts Framework.

Herewith i have added coding below,

my database(account_dao):

[image: account_dao]

my database(add_customer_dao):

[image: add_customer_dao]

my action class(add_customer_action):

```
    public static List getCustomerList(String customerName) {
    List customerList = null;
    long id = 0;
    String customer_Name = new String();
    try {
        /*Create Session Factory Object*/
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        /*Creating Session Object*/
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        /*Creating Transaction Object*/
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        try {
            /*Get Customer Full Name from DB where Login Name*/
            Query customer_name = session.createQuery("from add_customer_dao where customerLogin=?");
            customer_name.setString(0, customerName);
            List Customer_Name = customer_name.list();
            for (Iterator iterator = Customer_Name.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                add_customer_dao Customer_Dao = (add_customer_dao) iterator.next();
                customer_Name = Customer_Dao.getCustomerfullName().trim();
                System.out.println("Customer Full Name : "+customer_Name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        try {
            /*Get Customer Account Id from DB*/
            Query account_id = session.createQuery("from account_dao where name=?");
            account_id.setString(0, customerName);
            List Account_Id = account_id.list();
            for (Iterator iterator = Account_Id.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                account_dao Account_Dao = (account_dao) iterator.next();
                id = Account_Dao.getId();
                System.out.println("Account Id : " + id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        try {
            if (id != 0) {
                /*Get CustomerList from DB where account_id*/
                Query customer_list = session.createQuery("from add_customer_dao where accountId=?");
                customer_list.setInteger(0, (int) id);
                customerList = customer_list.list();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    return customerList;
}
```

my bean class(add_customer_dao):

```
public class add_customer_dao {

private int customerId;
private int accountId;
private String customerfullName;
private String customerLogin;
private String customerPassword;
private String confirmPassword;
private String customerRole;
private String customerMobile;
private String customerTelephone;
private String customerAddress;

 //Getter and Setter Methods
 }
```

my bead class(account_dao):

```
 public class account_dao {

//Declare Variable
private long loginId;
private String name;
private String password;
private String role;
//Getter and Setter Methods
}
```

my jsp file(business.jsp):

```
 <li> <a href=#><span class=icon-pencil></span> All Customers</a>
                    <ul>
                        <%
                            session.setAttribute("customerList", add_customer_action.getCustomerList(account_name));
                        %>
                        <logic:iterate name="customerList" id="list">
                            <li><a href=form_elements.html><bean:write name="list" property="customerfullName"/></a></li>
                        </logic:iterate>
                        <!--                            <li><a href=form_elements.html>Form elements</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href=form_editors.html>WYSIWYG and upload</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href=form_validation.html>Validation and wizard</a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Pls Help me, how can i display dynamic tree view for data from Database......

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it's time to upgrade, struts1 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade to Struts2 (since struts1 is officially deprecated).

You can use any libraries out there to draw a dynamic tree - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+tree&oq=jquery+tree&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l3j69i60l2.2460j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

I've used [struts2-jquery-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) in the past to draw dynamic trees.